# Override detected WIFI parameters

Tags: 2.1-eclair, wi-fi

I am trying to connect to our corporate WIFI network. I **know** that the type of the network is 802.1x because tech support told me so and I have colleagues that can connect to it using their iPhone with that type of authentication.

My problem is that my phone (Android 2.1) detects the network security as WEP and I can't override it. I tried to manually add a network with the same SSID and the correct configuration. However, when I look at the wireless networks, it says that only the detected network is in range, and that the one I added manually is out of range.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You should probably talk to your IT department.  They would certainly be able to help you, probably faster than you could get help on here too.

They may also have some settings that are restricting unauthorized devices from connecting.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to connect to 802.1x networks when I had 2.1 on my phone.  I don't think they were supported.  I can connect now that I have 2.2 though.

Comment: I don't know if connecting actually works, but the wireless settings have an option for that. I doubt they would added that feature if it didn't work, at least in some scenarios.

Comment: Probably true...